# SSH into GKE Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a GKE Kubernetes cluster that I would like to debug.

Is it possible to start a container inside the cluster using e.g. `ubuntu` image and SSH into it with full privileges, so I will be able to install software inside it with `apt` and run various debugging commands?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all it's possible to deploy a `pod` with a single container consisting of `ubuntu` targeting a namespace or even a node.

Rather than using SSH to connect to it (which is possible using an extensive combination of either using a `LoadBalancer` or exposing a `NodePort`) it's easier to use the `kubectl` tool.

If you're using `Cloud Shell` it's already installed or if using local laptop you have to install it using the `gcloud` tool.

I would suggest connecting to the container directly using the following syntax:

```
# Run bash on Ubuntu container
kubectl exec -it ubuntu -- bash

# General syntax
kubectl -n {namespace} exec -it {pod-name} -- {command}
```

First command assumes the container name is `ubuntu` and in the current namespace. The second command gives the general format.

Example `ubuntu` pod definition:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ubuntu
  labels:
    app: ubuntu
spec:
  containers:
  - image: ubuntu
    command:
      - "sleep"
      - "604800"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: ubuntu
  restartPolicy: Always
```

You can add a `namespace` to it or ensure you have the right context before applying. Something like:

```
kubectl apply -f path/to/yaml/file
```

Comment: Thanks, could you also add an example of such pod creation? Is it possible to do in a single command without the need to create a manifest file beforehand?

Comment: Updated with pod example.